# MQuery to write a particular case condition in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a particular if else situation which I have to implement in PowerBI using a M Query Code

CASE WHEN ‘A’ = '' OR ‘A’ IS NULL
AND
'B’ = '' OR 'B’ IS NULL
THEN 'SELF'
ELSE
‘A’
END

So as per above condition I have to check if A is null or '' and if B is null or ''
If yes then change value of A to SELF else remain A as it is

I tried with below M Query but it is failing
#"Result"=Table.TransformColumn(#"PreviousStep",{{"A",each
if (_ = null or _ = "") and ([B] = null or [B] = "") then "SELF" else _}})

But it says we cannot apply field access to the type NULL .
I tried multiple different option but getting same error ,
Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your M Query doesn't make sense, there isn't a `Table.TransformColumn` function.

Here's how you can update column [A] based on conditions:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(PreviousStep, each [A], each if ([A] = "" or [A] = null) and ([B] = "" or [B] = null) then "SELF" else [A], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"A"})
```

Comment: I do not want to create New column but only edit the column A , i.e. why I was using Table.Transform Instead of Table.Add
I can easily use Table.Add to create new column , remove original column and then rename new to original , but I am checking if there can be a better way of doing it .

Comment: Updated answer to update column A  (wasn't clear in the question).